# Visa refusal - Will this be a problem?

Tags: student-visa, uk-visa

I completed my Bachelor's in business and am currently working in my family business. I planned to do my Master's in London. So when I went to an agent, they directed me to apply for an EEA visa. I was refused twice, for the reason that I'm financially strong, and that I do not need to be a dependent. Now I'm planning to apply to Australia for my studies. I understand I was directed into wrong the category. Will this be a problem?

Comment: Why don't you apply for a visa in the UK in the correct category?